# Garden & Greenhouse pest! Mice? Vole? Rabbit?

Tags: pests

The last 3 years something has eaten everything young in my garden, other than potatoes, onions, and chives. They just mow off the leaves, and sometimes the stems to the ground. They also dig the corn and sunflower seeds out of the ground!they leave everything alone once it gets bigger. No visible tunnels or footprints.  This year I started plants indoors and moved them to the greenhouse. Most things are bigger, but I had some young peppers, maybe 2 inches high that have been eaten! I know a rabbit couldn't climb, but that doesn't make them innocent in the garden. Help!!!!

Comment: Welcome to the site Jackie! Where do you live? I ask that to narrow down the choices, or add some not all of us see in our yard. Also, do you ever see pieces of leaves or stems that have been "picked off" by your visitor? If so, are they in your garden by the base of your plants, or elsewhere as if carried away?

Answer (score 1):

...chipmunks/squirrels are not on your list (and should be), but everything on the list is plausible in the garden - depending how tight the greenhouse is (if you are saying the greenhouse is also getting hit) that might remove a few from the list.

These days, if you can't catch them by going out at night with a flashlight, you can set up a video camera with IR lighting and capture images of what's after your plants.

For the greenhouse, at least, screening all the openings with a fairly fine mesh should stop most things.

Answer (score -2):

Most animals love the smell of dryer lint, so you could put some of that in the garden to choke the animal eating your food. If you want to make it smell sweeter you could add some sugar.

Comment: The question was about an id, not about killing it. Besides, who says OP has only the seed-robber visiting the garden?

Comment: That's what I would do to solve the pest problem, and using lint is a lot safer than pestacides.

Comment: Seeing some dead rodents would help identify the problem.

Comment: Do you have sources that back up this method as lethal? I did some googling, but found nothing. Mice love dryer lint as nesting material, though.